# Are there external enclosures allowing external drives to be connected to internal motherboard?

Tags: enclosures

i have four SATA drives, inside the server case, each connected to a SATA port:

```
+============================+
|                            |
|    SATA2_1 <======== WDC   |
|    SATA2_2 <======== WDC   |
|    SATA2_3 <======== WDC   |
|    SATA2_4 <======== WDC   |
|                            |
+============================+
```

The cooling in the server isn't what i would like, so i've been looking at better cases - with a focus on cooling hard drives, e.g.:

[image]

Then i thought that perhaps there are steel boxes designed to hold, and power, SATA drives externally:

[image]

while still allowing them to be connected to the motherboard:

```
+============================+     +=============
|                            |     |            |
|    SATA2_1 <===============+=====+===== WDC   |
|    SATA2_2 <===============+=====+===== WDC   |
|    SATA2_3 <===============+=====+===== WDC   |
|    SATA2_4 <===============+=====+===== WDC   |
|                            |     |            |
+============================+     +============+
```

i get the sense that such technology does no exist. Does such technology exist?

---

**Note**: i'm not talking about an external enclosure that handles read/writes to the drives themselves, and is connected to the computer via

- USB 3.0, or
- eSATA, or
- SAS

The reason i'm not talking about those is because if that enclosure has a system failure i lose all my data.

i'm only looking for better *cooling* for internal external hard drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Burly's kit:

[Burly 4 Bay SATA kit](http://www.burlystorage.com/index.php?app=ecom&ns=prodshow&ref=SATAKIT4BAY&sid=52t08451ccnxzx805ao882j52080pf06)

[Short review](http://www.macgurus.com/productpages/sata/sataguide_1.php)

You'll also need the adapters Dennis linked to.

EDIT: just in case you only have two free slots for the plates you can get

[2-port adapters](http://www.lindy-usa.com/2-port-esata-backplate-adapter-33236.html)

Comment: i see it really is a smaller $300 case, with SATA-eSATA adapters.

Answer (score 3):

eSATA is very different from USB, and you can use it without worries.

From [Serial ATA # eSATA - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#eSATA):

> Standardized in 2004, eSATA (e standing for external) provides a variant of SATA meant for external connectivity. It uses a more robust connector, longer shielded cables, and stricter (but backward-compatible) electrical standards. The protocol and logical signaling (link/transport layers and above) are identical to internal SATA. [...]
>
> Aimed at the consumer market, eSATA enters an external storage market served also by the USB and FireWire interfaces. The SATA interface has certain advantages. Most external hard-disk-drive cases with FireWire or USB interfaces use either PATA or SATA drives and "bridges" to translate between the drives' interfaces and the enclosures' external ports; this bridging incurs some inefficiency.

As you can see, an external enclosure using eSATA won't handles read/writes to the drives by itself.

Adapters like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GV5WBE) turn an internal SATA port into an external one.

Comment: The problem is that i only have 1 eSATA port, but 4 SATA drives.

Comment: Did you check out the adapter in my answer?

Comment: But is there a mechanism in these external boxes then to connect *four* SATA cables to them? Rather than just one?

Comment: i see there *is* a SATA technology, call *Port Multiplying*, allowing multiple drives to be connected to a single SATA port. The total bandwidth is limited to that of the single SATA cable. The protocol also only allows one drive to be addressed at a time, that request must be issued and completed before the host can address another drive. This eliminates the value of NCQ (*native command queuing*)

Comment: Be aware that not all SATA ports support port multipliers. Onboard ports usually don't.